# How to move customer information from ASP.NET database to your database?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm using CreateUserWizard for creating an user but asp.net automatically add user to ASP.NET database
I want to add user in my database and in my customer table.
I have tried these code as peer below but nothing happened

```
private MembershipUser _CurrentUser = null;
    private MembershipUser CurrentUser
    {
        get
        {
            if (_CurrentUser == null)
            {
                _CurrentUser = Membership.GetUser(HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name);
            }
            return _CurrentUser;
        }
    }


    protected void CreateUserWizard1_CreatedUser(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        ProfileCommon p = (ProfileCommon)ProfileCommon.Create(CreateUserWizard1.UserName, true);

              p.FirstName = ((TextBox)CreateUserWizard1.CreateUserStep.ContentTemplateContainer.FindControl("FirstName")).Text;
        p.LastName = ((TextBox)CreateUserWizard1.CreateUserStep.ContentTemplateContainer.FindControl("LastName")).Text;
        p.ContactNumber = ((TextBox)CreateUserWizard1.CreateUserStep.ContentTemplateContainer.FindControl("ContactNumber")).Text;

        // Save profile - must be done since we explicitly created it
        p.Save();
    }
```

Please help me to figure out my problem

Comment: Hey @Tara, could you please follow up the issue or close the question.

Answer (score 0):

You need to look at your web.config file and provide a different connection string for the default membership provider.  Try this, but with your connection string.

```
<connectionStrings>
    <remove name="LocalSqlServer"/>
    <add name="LocalSqlServer" connectionString="Data Source=myServer;Initial Catalog=myDB;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

Note that you will have to copy the all membership and role tables from the "ASP.NET database" to your database for your login etc. to continue working.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the CreatedUser event and call a method to insert a new customer to your customers table.

```
protected void CreateUserWizard1_CreatedUser(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    CreateCustomer(CreateUserWizard1.UserName, CreateUserWizard1.Email);
    // Your code here
}
```

And then implement a method to create the customer:

```
public void CreateCustomer(string userName, string email)
{
    const string insertCustomerCommand = "INSERT INTO Customers (userName, email) VALUES (@userName, @email)";

    var connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["myConnectionString"];
    var sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(connectionString.ToString());
    var sqlCommand = new SqlCommand(insertCustomerCommand, sqlConnection);

    sqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@userName", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = userName;
    sqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@email", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = email;

    // Eventually wrap in a try catch statement to handle any sql exceptions.
    sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Following your code, it should be something like this:

```
protected void CreateUserWizard1_CreatedUser(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var customer = new Customer();
    customer.InsertCustomer(CUSTOMER_ID,                // Provide a unique customer Id
                            TextboxFirstName.Text,      // Provider the control that holds the first name
                            TextboxLastName.Text,       // Provider the control that holds the last name
                            TextboxContactNumber.Text,  // Provider the control that holds the contact number
                            CreateUserWizard1.Email,    
                            CreateUserWizard1.UserName);
}
```

You must provide a valid customer Id. Do have any method in your Sql Helper class to generate this?

Comment: Is it the customer ID an index auto generated column?

Comment: No,It's not.What else can I do?

Comment: Ok, then you must have or create a stored procedure or query to fetch the new customer Id.